lags while using loops in python and the code doesn't stop
I've been learning python for two days and I'd like to write a script that reads cards on the table while playing poker and calculates the chance of winning. Here's what I've managed to write in 2 days of learning python. It somehow works but is there a way to make this code better? The task is to check whether there is a king of hearts (KH.png) or ace of hearts (AH.png) on the screen and do the math and stop the code. In my case I run the code, it works, but after the math it doesn't stop and then it begins to run very slowly (No ACES, No KINGS (print) appear with a very high delay)
import pied_poker as pp
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time
np.random.seed(420)
def kings_search():
    while 1:
        try:
            pyautogui.locateOnScreen('KH.png', confidence=0.9)
            card_one = "kh"
            card_two = "kd"
            print("KINGS!")
            p1 = pp.Player('Artur', pp.Card.of(card_one, card_two))
            p2 = pp.Player('Opponent', pp.Card.of()) # We don't know the opponent's cards, so we leave that empty
            community_cards = pp.Card.of("2h", "qh", "4h", "10c", "6c")
            print(p1)
            print(f'Community cards: {community_cards}')
            simulator = pp.PokerRound.PokerRoundSimulator(community_cards=community_cards, players=[p1, p2], total_players=2)
            num_simulations = 10000
            simulation_result=simulator.simulate(n=num_simulations, n_jobs=1)
            print(simulation_result.probability_of(pp.Probability.PlayerWins(p1)))
            break
        except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
            print("No KINGS")
            aces()


def aces():
    while 1:
        try:
            pyautogui.locateOnScreen('AH.png', confidence=0.9)
            card_one = "ah"
            card_two = "ad"
            print("ACES!")
            p1 = pp.Player('Artur', pp.Card.of(card_one, card_two))
            p2 = pp.Player('Opponent', pp.Card.of()) # We don't know the opponent's cards, so we leave that empty
            community_cards = pp.Card.of("2h", "qh", "4h", "10c", "6c")
            print(p1)
            print(f'Community cards: {community_cards}')
            simulator = pp.PokerRound.PokerRoundSimulator(community_cards=community_cards, players=[p1, p2], total_players=2)
            num_simulations = 10000
            simulation_result=simulator.simulate(n=num_simulations, n_jobs=1)
            print(simulation_result.probability_of(pp.Probability.PlayerWins(p1)))
            break
        except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
            print("No ACES")
            kings_search()
aces()

I actually don't know what to do with that.

So the issue you are having is twofold.

the aces() and kings_search() are both in while loops that never really break unless an item is found in both of the loops.
the aces() and kings_search() call each other vice versa -- when the element is not found so you keep creating instances of each of the function to run indefinitely.

Here is a suggestion for the code that you should use (just a single check of whether there is a king or ace at a time during your game event loop)
def find_item_on_screen(card_image, card_one, card_two, card_type) -> bool: # returns a TF value to use elsewhere # generic function that handles finding cards of multiple types
    try:
        pyautogui.locateOnScreen(card_image, confidence=0.9)
        print(f"{card_type}!")
        p1 = pp.Player('Artur', pp.Card.of(card_one, card_two))
        p2 = pp.Player('Opponent', pp.Card.of()) # We don't know the opponent's cards, so we leave that empty
        community_cards = pp.Card.of("2h", "qh", "4h", "10c", "6c")
        print(p1)
        print(f'Community cards: {community_cards}')
        simulator = pp.PokerRound.PokerRoundSimulator(community_cards=community_cards, players=[p1, p2], total_players=2)
        num_simulations = 10000
        simulation_result=simulator.simulate(n=num_simulations, n_jobs=1)
        print(simulation_result.probability_of(pp.Probability.PlayerWins(p1)))
        return True
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        print(f"No {card_type}")
        return False

def check_king():
    locate_item = 'KH.png'
    card_one = "kh"
    card_two = "kd"
    card_type = 'KING'
    find_item_on_screen(locate_item, card_one, card_two, card_type)    

def check_aces(): # a more specific function for aces when you have a generic function find_item_on_screen()
    locate_item = 'AH.png'
    card_one = "ah"
    card_two = "ad"
    card_type = 'ACES'
    find_item_on_screen(locate_item, card_one, card_two, card_type)

check_king() # how to call each of the functions # place these inside of the area that you are running the game
check_aces()


